# Date Math for Google Apps Script for User Submitted Dates

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a Google Form to collect user input, including the expiration date of a contract.

I need to create a reminder date (6 months before the expiration date) in a new column of the gsheets that is linked to the form. Using the Event Object namedValues, I extracted the expiration date from gsheet. I converted the date to milliseconds and subtracted the number of milliseconds equal to 6 months (or thereabouts). However, the output that got sent back to the googlesheet is an undefined number.

I must be misunderstanding something and was hoping someone more skilled in this can help me out. Is the data type wrong? Thanks for any illumination you can provide.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  
    var responses = e.namedValues;
    var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    var expireDate = responses['Expiration Date'][0].trim();
    var expireDate_ms = expireDate * 1000; // converting to milliseconds
    var noticeDate = expireDate_ms - (183 * MILLIS_PER_DAY);
            
    // Create a new column to store the date to send out notice of expiration or renewal
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
    var column = e.values.length + 1;
    sheet.getRange(row, column).setValue(noticeDate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I’d recommend you to use a formula instead:

```
={"Reminder"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B2:B)); EDATE(B2:B; -6); ""))}
```

Add this to the header of an empty column, it will generate all data in that column for you. Change `B` for the column you have the expiration date on.

If you really need to use Google Apps Script you can, but JavaScript is notorious for having bad date support (at least without an external library). To do it, you’ll have to manually parse the string, modify the date and format it back to the date number:

```js
 const dateParts = e.namedValues['Expiration Date'][0].trim().split('/')
 const date = new Date(
   Number(dateParts[2]), // Year
   Number(dateParts[1]) - 1 - 6, // Month. -1 because January is 0 and -6 for the 6 months before
   Number(dateParts[0]) // Day
 )
 const numericDate = Math.floor((date.getTime() - new Date(1900, 0, 1).getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
```

This example only works if the format used in the sheet is `DD/MM/YYYY`.

The numeral value of date is the number of days since the first day of 1900 ([link to documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092969?hl=en&ref_topic=3105385)). So we need to subtract it and change it from milliseconds to days. `Math.floor` ensures that it’s not decimal.

You can set `numericDate` to the cell but make sure the numeric format is `Date`.

### References

- [EDATE - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092974?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [Date - JavaScript (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
- [DATE - Docs Editor Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092969?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Marti's answer was helpful but the math didn't quite work out because the suggested solution was to minus 6 from the month retrieved. But the reminder date is supposed to be 6 months from the date (taking into account the year and the date), so it doesn't quite work.

The solution I worked out is the following:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  
  const expireDateParts = e.namedValues['Expiration Date'][0].trim();
  
  if (expireDateParts != ""){
    expireDateParts.split('/');
    var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;  
    
    const expireDate = new Date(
        Number(expireDateParts[2]), // Year
        Number(expireDateParts[0]) - 1, // Month. -1 because January is '0'
        Number(expireDateParts[1]) // Day
    );
    
    const reminderNumericDate = Math.floor((expireDate.getTime() - 183 * MILLIS_PER_DAY));
    var reminderDate = formatDate(reminderNumericDate);
  
    // Create a new column to store the date to send out notice of expiration or renewal
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
    var column = 14 // hard-coded to Column 0;
    sheet.getRange(row, column).setValue(reminderDate);
  
    // Set up Schedule Send Mail
    createScheduleSendTrigger(reminderNumericDate); 
    var status = 'Scheduled';
    sheet.getRange(row, column+1).setValue(status);
    
  }
}
```